# Error interacting with the smart contract - bid() function

Tags: debugging, solidity

When I interact with the smart contract all functions seems to work but bid(), if I try to input any value it directly handle it as an error giving the 'sorry, the bid is not enough' message.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.1;

contract Auction{
address payable public beneficiary;
uint public auctionEndTime;

    //Track auction status
    address public highestbidder;
    uint public highestbid;
    bool ended;
    
    mapping(address => uint) pendingReturns;
    
    event highestBidIncreased(address bidder, uint amount);
    event auctionEnded(address winner, uint amount);
    
    constructor(uint _biddingTime, address payable _beneficiary){
        beneficiary= _beneficiary;
        auctionEndTime=block.timestamp+_biddingTime;
        highestbid=0;
    }
    
    function bid(uint _bid) public payable {
        if(block.timestamp>auctionEndTime) revert('the auction has ended');
        if(msg.value<=highestbid) revert('sorry, bid is not enough');
        if(highestbid!=0){
            pendingReturns[highestbidder]+=highestbid;
        }
        highestbidder=msg.sender;
        highestbid=msg.value;
        emit highestBidIncreased(msg.sender, msg.value);
    
    }
    
    function withdraw() public payable returns(bool){
        uint amount=pendingReturns[msg.sender];
        if (amount>0){
            pendingReturns[msg.sender]=0;
        }
        if(!payable(msg.sender).send(amount)){
            pendingReturns[msg.sender]=amount;
        }
        return true;
    }
    
    function auctionEnd() public{
        if(block.timestamp<auctionEndTime) revert('The auction has not ended yet');
        if(ended) revert('the auction is already over');
    
        ended=true;
        emit auctionEnded(highestbidder, highestbid);
        beneficiary.transfer(highestbid);
    }

}
```

I think I can pass msg.value as parameter but I cant figure out how without having issues compiling

Answer (score 0):

The function `bid` is payable, and `msg.value` contains the amount of wei sent in the transaction. If you don't associate any wei to the transaction, the condition `msg.value <= highestbid` will evaluate false and then the execution will revert.